# Efficiently getting the closest value in a list of numbers in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'll be the first to admit that I know next to nothing about SQL, so I know that is likely a better way of doing what I'm attempting to do, which is the reason that I'm here. I have a list of numbers, and I'm trying to get the entry in the database in which is closest (less than or equal to) that number, for every number in the list. I know, for example, that if I had a list of numbers and I was attempting to find the entries with the column equal to those values it would be something like:

```
SELECT valueA, valueB, valueC 
    FROM TableA 
    WHERE valueC in (num1, num2, num3, num4...);
```

However, I'm not sure how or if it's possible to combine in and the lte operator. So, what I'm currently doing is a `SELECT` statement for each value in the list like this:

```
SELECT valueA, valueB, valueC
    FROM TableA
    WHERE valueC <= num1
    ORDER BY valueC DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Which works fine when the size of my list is small, but when it's rather large, i.e. in the magnitude of several million, this takes a very, very, long time to finish as each list item requires it's own SQL call.

So is there any better way to do this, or, if I'm still required to have call for every list item, a more efficient way of getting the greatest value less than or equal to the list item without ordering the result list and getting the first?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Are the numbers (num1, num2, num3, num4) sorted ascending?

Comment: Not currently, but they can be.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is changing the `IN` clause since you said `<=` like

```
SELECT valueA, valueB, valueC
    FROM TableA
    WHERE (num1, num2, num3, num4...) IN valueC
    ORDER BY valueC DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Another way is to having this list values populated in a temp table like

```
create temporary table tbl1(col int);
insert into tbl1
values(num1, num2, num3, num4...);
```

Perform your query like

```
SELECT valueA, valueB, valueC
    FROM TableA ta
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tbl1 WHERE col <= ta.valueC)
    ORDER BY valueC DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: The problem with the first suggestion is that many of the numbers in the list are not in valueC, which is why I'm looking for the closest value lte to it. e.g. the values for valueC in the table would be [1, 5, 9, 10] and I have a list of numbers, [6, 54], which should return the entries where valueC is equal to [5, 10].

Comment: Give a try to the second alternative then and see how it goes.

Comment: Will do! Thanks for the help, and I'll get back to you asap.

Answer (score -1):

If the list in parenthesis is sorted ascending you can try the following

```
SELECT valueA, valueB, valueC
FROM TableA
WHERE valueC <= ANY (num1, num2, num3 ...);
```

However I don't know if ANY clause is supported in SQLite.

For a single valueC the query stops list evaluation as soon it finds a less than or equal value inside the list.